# HttpWebRequest Hanging

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

In the application I am currently working on there is a backend java app that is caching a bunch of data. The asp.net part is allowing users to update database tables. Each time the DB is updated the cache in the java application should be cleared. So basically I have a list of 4 URLs that each need to be hit in order to clear the cache. My basic solution was to loop through each url and create a HttpWebRequest and get then get the response. So basically I have this for each request:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentLength = 0;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    string responseString = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                    returnList.Add(string.Format("Refresh response from {0}.<br />{1}", url, responseString));

                    readStream.Close();
                    receiveStream.Close();
                }
```

On my local machine everything works great. But when I deploy to our development server it just hangs and does nothing. If I remove `request.ContentLength = 0;` then the remote server throws a 411: Length expected error.

I am really stuck here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Either a solution to the HttpWebRequest problem I am having or a different solution to calling each URL would work, I'm not picky.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this was a network issue. I tried hitting a different url (the load balancer) and had no problems so the java guys are making a changes so I can just hit the load balancer and whatever server the request ends up on will make sure all servers caches are cleared.

The code that is working:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string responseString = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                returnString = string.Format(@"Refresh response from<br />{0}{1}", url, responseString);

                readStream.Close();
                receiveStream.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are using request.method as "POST"? Are you posting any data, if not try removing both content length and request method.